# Is it possible for openmp to run different threads on a same cpu(core)

Tags: c++, c, openmp

Assume I have two cores. Let us denote them as core1 and core2. If I use openmp to parallelize my program, two threads will be generated. Is it possible for openmp implementation to allocate both of the two threads on core1 to excute instead of on core1 and core2? In the first case we will lose parallelism.

I am using Intel openmp included with icc. By default, is it possible to run different threads on a same cpu(core)

Thanks.

Comment: The OS will schedule the threads, not OpenMP, and yes, it is perfectly possible for multiple threads to run on the same core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to instruct the OpenMP runtime to do specific binding (or pinning in Intel's terminology) of the threads to the available CPU cores. OpenMP 4.0 comes with provisions to specify this in an abstract and portable way, while current OpenMP implementations provide their own specific mechanisms to do it:

- `KMP_AFFINITY` for Intel compilers - see [here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/optaps/common/optaps_openmp_thread_affinity.htm);
- `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY` for GCC (and Intel in compatibility mode) - see [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/GOMP_005fCPU_005fAFFINITY.html).

Unless these are set, both runtimes default to no binding and the OS is free to dispatch the threads as it deems fit, e.g. it might dispatch both threads on a single core. The latter is rather unlikely unless there are other running processes that require lots of CPU time. Still most OS schedulers tend to constantly migrate threads and processes around, therefore it is advisable that you employ the binding mechanisms for maximum performance.

Comment: How do I set the thread affinity in OpenMP 4.0 in an abstract and portable way?

Comment: The OpenMP4.0 specificiation to the rescue.  I guess it's set through `proc_bind`.  It's time to upgrade to GCC 4.x to start using OpenMP4.0 (I have more or less given up on MSVC now).

Comment: GCC 4.9 should provide support for most OpenMP 4.0 constructs.